# Profiling C++ compilation times in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, build

I'm currently working on speeding-up the building process of a fairly large C++ codebase. While the process of improving compilation times of specific translation units is pretty well understood and documented I don't think there are any tools that would help me profile the building process to find candidates for optimisation - at least not for Visual Studio as I've read of some that would facilitate the process in GCC or Clang.

To better illustrate my problem, I'll give you a simple example:

Let's assume we have a large header file that includes multiple other headers. Including it in a .cpp file greatly degrades its compilation time. Let's say that it is included in many translation units and therefore optimising it will improve the overall building time by a lot.

Do you know of any tools that would help identify such heavy-hitters?

I've begun writing a Python script that parses Visual Studio build logs and creates a dependency graph and then analyses it, but I'd like to make sure that this work is indeed necessary.

Comment: @meagar I could reword my question to ask for opinions on "how would one approach profiling C++ builds" instead of asking for tools. The reason I posted a link to the tool I've created was not to promote, but rather inform people that a tool that I don't think existed before was created. Again, I could reword it to explain the approach I've chosen and the results I got... or link to the README at github as it describes it all in detail. I don't really care, just wanted to leave this info here to possibly help someone out in the future. Would that work for you?